# Sync data between EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While I'm looking to move our servers to AWS, I'm trying to figure out how to sync data between our web nodes.
I would like to mount a disk on every web node and have a local cache of the entire share.

Are there any preferred ways to do this?

Comment: what kind of data? and how often does it change?

Comment: Images, PDFs, videos etc. The files is updated every minute and the web nodes are working a lot with the files. Thats why I need a local cache.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you should consider storing your files on s3 originally and if performance is key, have a sync job that pulls copies of the files locally to your ec2 instance. S3 is fast, durable and cheap - maybe even fast enough without keeping a local cache - but if you do indeed need a local copy, there are tools such as the aws cli and other 3rd party tools.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you are trying to sync - take a look at

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/

It is an extremely fast and efficient method for sharing data.

Answer (score -2):

One absolute easy solution is to install Dropbox sync client on both the machines and keep your files in Dropbox. This is by far the easiest !

In this approach, you can "load" data to the machines, using externally adding files to your dropbox account (not even go to AWS service to load) - From another machine or even from browser interface of Dropbox.